# Randomly select non adjacent polygons in vector layer (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, sampling, neighbour

I am trying to obtain a random selection of polygons (e.g., 100 polygons out of 400) with the condition that the selected polygons are not adjacent among each other.
Any suggestion on how to achieve this result in QGIS?

Comment: Can you specify your need a bit more ? (Selecting one random polygon answers your current question). At which point do you stop selecting polygons ?

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using something like topological coloring from the Processing toolbox to assign colors to your polygons, then pick one of the colors and use one of the random selection methods from the Processing Toolbox to select within that color .

Note that as the desired number of randomly selected polygons increases it may not be possible to achieve the desired result as there may not be that many non-adjacent polygons. Furthermore, the non-adjacency criterion complicates the interpretation of "random". For some number there will be exactly one subset. Is that "random"? For small to moderate sized n, there will be choices of non-adjacent polygons that do not exist within the coloring. Bottom line, the approach suggested above will give sets of non-adjacent polygons, but not every possible satisfying subset will be selected with equal probability, and some may not be chosen at all.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.
You are correct, the selection will not be random anymore, at least not in the standard sense. However, I believe (but I need to think more about it) that as long as the coloring of the polygons is random one will get a random selection of polygons within the subet of possible combinations (i.e. non adjacent).   Does this makes sense to you?

Comment: Ok, it works. But how do I set the polygon layer to be colored according to the color category?

Comment: @Caserio - The coloring will almost certainly not be random which means in turn there will be subsets of non-adjacent polygons that are not found.

Comment: @Caserio - in the symbology tab select categorized then color_id for the value parameter.Then click on classify

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to:

1. Random extract polygons (more than you expect at the end): `random` layer
2. Dissolve this layer while makins sure the ***Keep disjoint features separate*** option is selected: `dissolved` layer
3. Use the `Extract by location` tool  selecting features from the `random` layerwhich  `contain` the `dissolved` layer

Last step will remove overlapping polygons that made it through step 1

In case of overlapping polygons after stage 1, it unfortunately removes both/all, there might be a more clever way to keep one but I have not found.

Comment: It is not clear what I need to do in step 3. Could you please explain?

Comment: I have edited the Answer to make it clearer